# how to get the server response.responseText after store load extjs 4

Tags: extjs4, extjs-mvc

I'm having one problem with getting the `response.responseText` from the server response in extjs 4.

Below is my code to load the store:

```js
store.load({
    params: {
        'projectid': this.projectid
    },
    callback: function (records, operation, success, response) {
        console.log(records);
        console.log(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

Actually, when I made the request with the below function, I properly get the `reponse.responseText`.

```js
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'login/GetLoginCheck.action',
    method: 'GET',
    params: {
        'username': values['username'],
        'password': values['password']
        },
    scope: this,
    success: function(response) {
        Ext.Msg.alert(response.responseText);
        var redirect = response.responseText;
        window.location.href = "" + redirect + ".jsp";
    },
    failure: function(response) {
        Ext.Msg.alert('INVALID USERNAME OR PASSWORD');
    }
});
```

So please suggest me how can I get the `response.responseText` from the store.load() having a callback function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

callback has 3 parameters...
try this :

```
store.load({
    params: {
        'projectid': this.projectid
    },
    callback: function (records, operation, success) {
        console.log(operation.response.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: I have no "operation.response" when the server returns 500. When server response the error message with status 500, I have to use Ext.Ajax.request to show the message and stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced a similar problem using [`Model.load(...)`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-static-method-load), but in my case, `operation.response` was not defined. So, I have found another way to get it :

```
Model.load(1, {
    success: function () {
        // I haven't tested inside this callback yet
    },
    failure: function (record, operation) {
        var response = operation.request.proxy.reader.rawData;
        alert(response.message);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> You may also try this..

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
    fields[],
    proxy:{url:'store_url.json', reader:{type:'json',root:'data'}},
    autoLoad:true,
    listeners:{
        load:function(store, record, success, opts){
            var response_text = store.proxy.reader.rawData;
            console.log(response_text);
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: this is what im looking for. the `response` parameter in the `callback` function of `store.load` would be undefined if `success == false`

Answer (score 0):

In extjs 3.4 you can use this:

```
this.historyInvoiceHeaderGrid.store.load({
        params:{start:0, limit:20},
        callback: function (records, operation, success) {
            console.log(this.reader.jsonData);
        }});
```

This property `store.reader.jsonData` will return full response.

Maybe for someone it would be usefull in extjs 3.

Answer (score 0):

In Extjs 4.x it is working like this

```
myStore.load({
        url: 'myurl',
        method: 'GET',
        callback: function(records, operation, success) {
        var jsonStr = Ext.JSON.decode(operation.response.responseText);
            alert(jsonStr.message);
         }
});
```

In Extjs 5 you have to do like this

```
myStore.load({
        url: 'myurl',
        method: 'GET',
        callback: function(records, operation, success) {
 var message=forecastMethodStore.getProxy().getReader().rawData.message;
         }
});
```

But the key point here is you should set the message in JSON response from java side.

> Sample: {"Root":[], "message":"duplicates"}"

Hope this will help someone.

Comment: Using ExtJs 4.1.3 and i have no response on the operation.

Answer (score 0):

You must set  `messageProperty` in `proxy reader` in your `'Ext.data.Store'`.

```
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'myDataList',
                totalProperty: 'myTotalRecord',
                successProperty: 'mySuccess',
                messageProperty : 'myMsg'
            }
```

when `mySuccess` returns `false` then invoked `callback: function`.

```
    store.load({
        params: {start: 0, limit: 15},
        callback: function (records, operation, success) {
            if (!success) {
                try {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Sorry !', operation.getError());
                    // operation.getError() returns myMsg value
                }catch (e){
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Exception !', e);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is a json return from Java Servlet.

```
    Map<String, Object> myDataMap = new HashMap<>(3);
    try {
        // Something
        myDataMap.put("mySuccess", true);
        myDataMap.put("myMsg", "Whats up khomeni !");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        myDataMap.put("mySuccess", false);
        myDataMap.put("myMsg", "Whats wrong with me.");
    }
    String json = new Gson().toJson(myDataMap);
```